# LDAP connection ldap_sasl_bind_s gives assertion

Tags: c++, c, linux, redhat, openldap

So I'm developing an LDAP application on Red Hat 5.5.

I've not done LDAP before so I'm reading documents as I go along.  I'm using OpenLDAP version 2.3

My source code looks like the following:

```
LDAP * ld;
int version=LDAP_VERSION3;
int retVal;
berval creds;
berval *serverCreds;

retVal= ldap_initialize(&ld,"ldap://myhost"); //myhost is an actual hostname.
if(retVal !=0)
{
    aWarning() << "Could not connect to host:" << hostname;
}

ldap_set_option(ld,LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION,&version);

creds.bv_val = "magic";  //These don't matter since I'm not using a cred mechanism.
creds.bv_len = strlen("magic");

cout << ldap_sasl_bind_s(ld,"uid=username, ou=groupname",NULL,&creds,NULL,NULL,servercred);

}
```

I've been following one of the only examples I could find of a c/c++ LDAP implementation here:

http://www-archive.mozilla.org/directory/csdk-docs/sasl.htm

But when I run this, I get the following error:

```
 ../../../libraries/libldap/sasl.c:108: ldap_sasl_bind: Assertion '((ber)->ber_opts.lbo_valid==0x2)' failed.
```

Based on some of my own research, I've it seems to suggest some sort of memory fault from a later version:

http://sourceforge.net/mailarchive/forum.php?thread_name=9F7FA2E0294A934CA0CD9E97BD580F840A801834%40CCS-EXCHANGE1.brynmill.swan.ac.uk&forum_name=vufind-tech

I'm curious if anyone familiar with LDAP sees any glaring mistakes or has seen this issue before.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this issue on Red Hat 6 when linking with both OpenLDAP `libldap.so` and Oracle's client library `libclntsh.so`, which embedded inside it has an Oracle implementation of the C LDAP API.

The issue is that OpenLDAP `libldap.so` requires library `liblber.so`, and if you don't explicitly link to it, these symbols are resolved by `libclntsh.so`, and hence are incompatible.

The fix is to add `-llber` to your linker line.

Note: on Red Hat 7, the error is different, you get -3 (LDAP_ENCODING_ERROR) 'Encoding error'.

Comment: This is the correct answer.  9 year ago me wasn't as good as I am now.  What seemed like a incorrect installation was actually library incompatibility because of bad linkage and having Oracle installed.

Answer (score 0):

As far as you provide a `cred` the `bv_len` need a correct value `strlen("magic");`

Answer (score 0):

Fixed issue:  It appears that our system admin had done the LDAP installation incorrectly and our libraries for our libldap.so and liblber.so where under different versions.  They linked ok but it caused some incompatibility at runtime that caused the assertions.

I haven't finished getting the bind to work yet as now I get a "can't contact LDAP server" error, but I'm going to mark this as answered since I did fix the assert issue.